How to remove highlighting of folders from oh-my-posh?
I recenlty installed oh-my-posh into my windows powershell and am using the catppuccin theme however when I use the dir command any sub-folders are highlighted in the output which I dont want.
highlighted subfolders image
I have tried changing the catppuccin.omp.json file but that doensn't seem to have any way to change it.
Does anyone know how to fix this?

To remove the highlighting of folders in oh-my-posh, you need to customize your theme configuration. The folder highlighting is typically defined in the theme's JSON configuration file under the properties or segment settings.
